# OpenSSL "Seal" in C (or via shell)

Tags: php, c, openssl, rsa

I'm working on porting some PHP code to C, that contacts a web API.

The issue I've come across is that the PHP code uses the function `openssl_seal()`, but I  can't seem to find any way to do the same thing in C or even via `openssl` in a call to `system()`.

From the PHP manual on `openssl_seal()`:

> int openssl_seal  ( string $data  ,
>   string &$sealed_data  , array
>   &$env_keys  , array $pub_key_ids  )
>
> openssl_seal() seals (encrypts) data
>   by using RC4 with a randomly generated
>   secret key. The key is encrypted with
>   each of the public keys associated
>   with the identifiers in pub_key_ids
>   and each encrypted key is returned in
>   env_keys . This means that one can
>   send sealed data to multiple
>   recipients (provided one has obtained
>   their public keys). Each recipient
>   must receive both the sealed data and
>   the envelope key that was encrypted
>   with the recipient's public key.

What would be the best way to implement this? I'd really prefer *not* to call out to a PHP script every time, for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are after the EVP ("Envelope Encryption") part of the C interface to the OpenSSL library:

```
#include <openssl/evp.h>

int EVP_SealInit(EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx, const EVP_CIPHER *type,
                 unsigned char **ek, int *ekl, unsigned char *iv,
                 EVP_PKEY **pubk, int npubk);
int EVP_SealUpdate(EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx, unsigned char *out,
        int *outl, unsigned char *in, int inl);
int EVP_SealFinal(EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx, unsigned char *out,
        int *outl);
```

(In this case, since you want RC4 for compatibility with the PHP code, you'd use `EVP_rc4()` as the `type` parameter to `EVP_SealInit()`).

Comment: Is there any code out there that uses this? I'm struggling with the documentation with no reference code I can find.

Comment: This is the first example I could find: http://www.gnu-darwin.org/www001/src/src/crypto/openssl/demos/maurice/example1.c.html - if that's not enough I'll try and put something together later today.

Comment: @user1436026: I've written an example in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9408355/134633).

Answer (score 1):

If you are allowed to use C++ and not just C You can use [Crypto++](http://www.cryptopp.com), it will easily do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Consider Crypto++ only if you have proficient knowledge in c++.