# rsa encryption decryption using c

Tags: c, openssl, rsa, encryption

I'm trying to write C code of RSA encryption and decryption using Open SSL. But I am not able to do so. I googled it but whatever code I got from internet it was out of my head. 
`main` function goes here which I got from stack overflow. I tried using it … but its not working. May be my bad.

```
encrypt(FILE *rsa_Pkey_fole,FILE *in_file,FILE *out_file){

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *rsa_pkey_file, *infile;
    int rv;

    if (argc < 2) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <PEM RSA Public Key File>\n", argv[0]);
            exit(1);
    }

    rsa_pkey_file = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    infile = fopen(argv[2], "w");
    if (!rsa_pkey_file) {
        perror(argv[1]);
        fprintf(stderr, "Error loading PEM RSA Public Key File.\n");
        exit(2);
    }

    rv = encrypt(rsa_pkey_file, infile.txt, stdout);
    fclose(rsa_pkey_file);

    return rv;
}
```

And similar way decryption.

How can I do RSA encryption and decryption of a file using Open SSL library in C in simple way?

Comment: "it's not working" isn't a particularly useful problem description.  http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: Please post the function encrypt, this main() won't tell us much...

Comment: sure.. i ll post the encryption part.. its little big.. and i m not able to understand..

Comment: @sakshi Could you please at least *try* to use proper english? This is not 4chan.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9406840/rsa-encrypt-decrypt.. dis s d link... plz suggest me simplest way... or better a link whr i can go thro about openssl network security...

Comment: @ FUZxxl hope my question is in human readable format.. so if possible try to answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Steps for RSA encryption are as follows:

1. **Read the public key into `RSA *` structure.** It depends on your key format. If key is in `PEM` format, use `PEM_read_RSA_PUBKEY` functions. If it is in `DER` form, use `d2i_RSA`.
2. **Encrypt your data using RSA public key.** Use `RSA_public_encrypt` function.
3. **Write the data to file or whatever you want to do.**

Steps for RSA decryption are:

1. **Read the private key into `RSA *` structure.** It is similar to step 1 in RSA encryption with some minor difference.
2. **Decrypt the data using `RSA_private_decrypt`.** Use `RSA_private_decrypt`.

You can look OpenSSL documentation which is quite useful and its names are intuitive. I give you just broad level idea. If you need more help, I can post the code example.

Comment: the man page for RSA_public_encrypt says you need to seed the RNG before calling, implying you need to get some random data from somewhere to pass to RAND_seed...