# C encrypting string with RSA pubkey

Tags: c, rsa

I have a problem with encrypting a string with my generated RSA pubkey. This key is stored in an unsigned char array. Here is an example of that key

```
char *testkey = "-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\n"
        "MIIBCgKCAQEA3InRLxdx25R6eA4PyXcYzKyFiJULS3ypqlETztAW488XkEM263vJ\n"
        "SY5xpfwph9thcsjYUI3H60qxaTRVhNxbzbsG0ELkEudm4cLMn2oVpphT4cB3zx6V\n"
        "az1cuzIfmL34M8YiRQw6MvdaDJS34y15dXDm0BSXF7sanZaYrHvu84j5mQVK0OWq\n"
        "kvpVs+J55xul/IQsSEWr94HjPupdDYzGXsEiQ7p5cNrvKgjGKqKV177EYROVVgVp\n"
        "gAWm0G6aDrfDLKqsXo8RXj4dyyuZqoL2e7Fa46Gz4I+tb2SWkEwLGpqBe/CUDzDh\n"
        "9aLhaTijDQhcaR5+u88XNbarckKU96wiiQIDAQAB\n"
        "-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----\0";
```

I have currently written this code to do the encryption

```
RSA                     *rsa = NULL;
BIO                     *key_bio;

static const int        bit = 2048;

key_bio = BIO_new_mem_buf(testkey, -1);

if(key_bio == NULL){
    printf("No key bio \n");
    exit(1);
}

rsa = PEM_read_bio_PUBKEY(key_bio, NULL, NULL, NULL);

if(rsa == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "Error loading RSA Public Key File.\n");


    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    exit(1);
}

// Alloc the encrypted buffer
e->enckey = calloc(1, 2048);

int res = RSA_public_encrypt(strlen((char*)e->key->key), e->key->key, e->enckey, rsa, RSA_PKCS1_PADDING);

if(res == -1){
    printf("Failed to encrypt AES key \n");
    printf("Error: strerror(errno)\n");
}
```

However, this do not work. I think it is something about the format of the key, however I have not managed to find out how to convert it, and use the RSA struct to do the encryption.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "this do not work"? Does it compile? Does it run? Are you getting any error messages? Are you getting any output? What is the expected behaviour? (Also, where is `e` declared? Why is this code missing?)

Comment: E is irrelevant. Just a struct with the data I am going to encrypt. Also a buffer for the encrypted data is stored there.

Program terminates because RSA = NULL, and prints an error: Expecting public key.

E is passed into this function from another one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [rsa encryption decryption using c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15652816/rsa-encryption-decryption-using-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be working fine now, using this insead:

```
PEM_read_bio_RSAPublicKey(key_bio, &rsa, 0, NULL);
```

The reason for this probably have something to do with the formats of the KEY.