# Segmentation fault when try to encrypt files in directory with C and opensll-lib

Tags: c, encryption

I try to create a program in C that encrypts all files in a directory using `openssl-lib`. I read the directory with `ntfw()` and pass the filename into handler function `handleCryptProcess()`. The fuction do the bellow procedures.

1. Create a temporary file to hold the cyphertext.
2. Encrypt the plaintext and output the results into cyphertext file.
3. Delete the plaintext file.
4. Rename the cyphertext file back to original one.

I use RSA public key to encrypt the file.

My problem is that I get **segmentation fault** when my folder contains more than one file. And that relates to the handler function. One or more of the above procedures can't handle the memory efficiently, I suppose.

When my folder contains **ONLY ONE** file then the procedure is **successful**.

Bellow is my handler function:

```
#include "crypt.h"

/**
 * - First we generate the filepath of our output file with getCyphertextFilePath().
 * - The we check (cryptFlag) and determine if we want to encrypt or decrypt the file.
 * - encryptRSAFile() tries to encrypt the file under (fpath).
 *   decryptRSAFile() tries to decrypt the file under (fpath).
 * - We delete the original file using unlink().
 * - Lastly, rename the new file back to original filename with rename().
 */
int handleCryptProcess(const char *fpath, const en_de_crypt_flag cryptFlag) {
    int status;
    char *new_fpath = NULL; /* Hold the file path of our output file */

    status = getOutputFilePath(fpath, &new_fpath);
    if (status == -1) {
        return -1; /* Could not get the output filepath. */
    }

    if (cryptFlag == ENCRYPT) { /* We want to encrypt our file. */
        status = encryptRSAFile(fpath, new_fpath);
    } else { /* We want to decrypt our file. */
        status = decryptRSAFile(fpath, new_fpath);
    }   
    if (status == -1) {
        return -1; /* Failed to encrypt/decrypt fpath. */
    }

    status = unlink(fpath); /* Delete the original file. */
    if (status == -1) {
        return -1; /* Failed to delete original fpath. */
    }
    status = rename(new_fpath, fpath); /* Rename our file. */
    if (status == -1) {
        return -1; /* Failed to rename back to original fpath. */
    }
    return 0; /* File encrypted/decrypted successfully. */
}
```

And here is the one I use to create the cyphertext:

```
#include "crypt.h"

/**
 * We use RSA asymmetric cryptography to create our cyphertext.
 * The public key was passed to (rsaPubKey) when we initialized it
 * in main() with publicRSATextKeyToStruct().
 * (fpath) is the file we want to encrypt.
 * (cyphertext_fpath) is our cyphertext.
 */
int encryptRSAFile(const char *fpath, const char *cyphertext_fpath) {
    FILE *fin, *fout;

    /**
     * Open the plaintext file we want to encrypt.
     */
    fin = fopen(fpath, "rb");
    if (fin == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }

    /**
     * Create a cyphertext file for writing to.
     */
    fout = fopen(cyphertext_fpath, "wb");
    if (fout == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }

    /**
     * The EVP_PKEY_new() function allocates an empty EVP_PKEY
     * structure which is used by OpenSSL to store private keys. 
     */
    EVP_PKEY *pkey = EVP_PKEY_new();

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX ctx; /* Cipher contex ctx. */
    unsigned char buffer[RSA_KEY_SIZE]; /* Buffer that holds out plaintext. */
    unsigned char buffer_out[RSA_KEY_SIZE + EVP_MAX_IV_LENGTH]; /* Buffer that holds the cyphertext. */
    size_t len;
    int len_out;

    /**
     * ek is an array of buffers where the public key encrypted secret key will be written, 
     * each buffer must contain enough room for the corresponding encrypted key.
     * That is ek[i] must have room for EVP_PKEY_size(pubk[i]) bytes
     */
    unsigned char *ek = NULL;
    int eklen;
    uint32_t eklen_n;
    unsigned char iv[EVP_MAX_IV_LENGTH]; /* Buffer where the generated IV is written to */


    if (!EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA(pkey, rsaPubKey)) {
        return -1;
    }

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(&ctx); /* Initialize a new context. */
    ek = malloc(EVP_PKEY_size(pkey));

    /**
     * EVP_SealInit() initializes a cipher context (ctx) for encryption 
     * with cipher type using a random secret key and (iv).
     * Cipher type we use is AES 256.
     * The secret key is encrypted using our public key (pkey).
     */
    if (!EVP_SealInit(&ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), &ek, &eklen, iv, &pkey, 1)) {
        return 2;
    }

    eklen_n = htonl(eklen);
    if (fwrite(&eklen_n, sizeof eklen_n, 1, fout) != 1) {
        return 3;
    }
    if (fwrite(ek, eklen, 1, fout) != 1) {
        return 4;
    }
    if (fwrite(iv, EVP_CIPHER_iv_length(EVP_aes_256_cbc()), 1, fout) != 1) {
        return 5;
    }

    while ((len = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof buffer, fin)) > 0) {
        if (!EVP_SealUpdate(&ctx, buffer_out, &len_out, buffer, len)) {
            return 6;
        }

        if (fwrite(buffer_out, len_out, 1, fout) != 1) {
            return 7;
        }
    }

    if (ferror(fin)) {
        return 8;
    }

    if (!EVP_SealFinal(&ctx, buffer_out, &len_out)) {
        return 9;
    }

    if (fwrite(buffer_out, len_out, 1, fout) != 1) {
        return 10;
    }

    EVP_PKEY_free(pkey);
    free(ek);
    fclose(fin);
    fclose(fout);
    return 0;
}
```

Does this have to do with the `return` values? Maybe is something with how do I check the error state. But I couldn't figure it out, and the openssl documentation is not very supportive in this.

### Update

To get a cleaner idea of what's happening I post an example.

Let's say we have two files.

- File1.ext
- File2.ext

The procedure start, reads the File1 encrypt it and go to File2.

On File2 my code breaks at the bellow condition on encrypt procedure:

```
fwrite(ek, eklen, 1, fout) != 1
```

then, I get an segmentation fault. This doesn't always happen in second file tough. If might be happen after the third one, but never up to forth.

If I have three files, I might encrypt the first one, the second one breaks the procedure and in the third one to get this error.

Comment: Your debugger should help your here.

Comment: Segmentation fault at what line of what file?

Comment: @MichaelWalz I update my question with more details now.

Comment: Look at the variables. You have the program running in your debugger. You can look at what it's doing. We can't.

Comment: @n.m. I can't see somthing interesting. What I have to look for exactly? The procedure was taken from this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9406840/rsa-encrypt-decrypt. It's in the nature of `fwrite` to be thread safe so I don't know what to see.

Comment: You need to have at least a vague idea of what variable has what value at any given moment. Look for obvious discrepancies. Is some variable that should never be NULL is? Is some variable that should never be negative is? etc.